# Python dateutil not parsing month

Tags: python, date, python-dateutil

I am getting the following stacktrace using `dateutil` to parse a date:

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('Sept 18 2014', fuzzy=True).date()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py", line     697, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py", line     310, in parse
    ret = default.replace(**repl)
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
```

This works:

```
dateutil.parser.parse('Sep 18 2014', fuzzy=True).date()
```

Any idea how I can fix this, given user input similar to the above?

Comment: What `dateutil` version are you using? What happens if you omit or set `fuzzy` to `False`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this issue was fixed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/dateutil/+bug/876900.

Installing the latest version of dateutil:

```
% pip install -U python-dateutil
Downloading/unpacking python-dateutil
  Downloading python-dateutil-2.2.tar.gz (259Kb): 259Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package python-dateutil
...
```

fixes the problem:

```
In [2]: import dateutil

In [3]: dateutil.parser.parse('Sept 18 2014').date()
Out[3]: datetime.date(2014, 9, 18)
```